# MySQL combining UPDATE and DELETE in one query

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-update, sql-delete

I'm aware of possibility of combining INSERT and UPDATE in single query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`x`, `y`) VALUES (1, 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `x`=`x`+1, `y`=`y`+2
```

But is it possible to combine in single query both `UPDATE` and `DELETE`? For example, I have such `table` in database:

```
id effect howlong
1     1     0
2     2     50
3     3     5
```

I'd like to substract 10 from whole `howlong` column where value is >0, and then delete all rows with `howlong`<=0 that was altered (if `howlong` was set to 0 before, it cannot be changed or deleted!). What would be the best way to do this?

I came up with two solutions, but both are just pseudocode that I'm unable to figure out how to implement as real code:

```
//First idea pseudocode:
UPDATE `table` SET `howlong`=`howlong`-10, DELETE ALTERED IF `howlong`<=0;
//Second idea pseudocode:
DELETE from `table` WHERE `howlong`>0 AND `howlong`<=10, SET `howlong`=`howlong`-10 WHERE `howlong`>0;
```

Is it possible in any way, or is it just science fiction and should I proceed with two separate queries?

Comment: No. Only INSERT and UPDATE actions pair may be performed in one query. Use stored procedure instead of query.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. Why just comment instead of answer?